# Mongoose only updating the first document even though multi option is set to true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this simplified Schema:

```
DealSchema = new db.Schema({

   _id : db.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   message : [{

      memberId : db.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      hasRead : Boolean

   }]

});
```

I want to update all documents that have the `hasRead` property from `false` to `true` based on the `memberId` and `_id` properties. So I executed this query:

```
var conditions = { _id : dealId, 'message.memberId' : loggedId }
,   update  = { $set : { 'message.$.hasRead' : true } };

    deal.Model
        .update(conditions, update, { multi : true }, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result); // outputs 1
            callback(err, result);
        });
```

The query has only been able to update the first subdocument it encountered. What I need it to do is to update all the matches. I'm pretty sure that it should affect at least more than 1 `message.hasRead` property in my db.

Any ideas? TIA

Comment: `conditions` matches against `_id` so how could this ever match more than one doc?

Comment: @JohnnyHK my bad. I actually meant more than 1 subdocument. The message property holds an array of objects with a default value of false for the hasRead property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` represents the index of just the *first* matching element.

Unfortunately, you can't update multiple array elements in a single update with the following exceptions/work-arounds:

1. You identify each targeted element in your `$set` via its 0-based index.
2. You (non-atomically) read the current doc, modify its `message` array, and then call `deal.save()`.

MongoDB does not have good support for this update pattern.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK. something as important as this should be implemented in the next versions :O. So basically, i'll have to execute a find() then loop through the results, update them and push them back while deleting the old copies. Did I get that right?

Comment: @AJNaidas No pushing or deleting of elements should be needed.  Loop through the `messages` array, update the elements in place, and call `save`.